# PHP array initialization speed vs memcache.get speed

Tags: php, performance, memcached

I have a big array with many strings like this:

```
$langArr = array( 'welcome' => 'Welcome!', 'hello' => 'Hello'...
```

I wonder if it is faster if I store it in memcache and just read it back from memcache instead of re-declare it again in PHP? I have searched but found no benchmark about PHP var declaration yet.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: if you're using some opcode cache it would be the same.

Comment: I just don't know if it's a best practice or not, is anybody doing the same way or there is another way to gain speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are just initializing the array from predetermined values:**

No it wouldn't be faster because when you bring the data from memcache back to PHP, PHP still has to build that array.

(Initialization time + latency + memcache speed) > Initialization time.

Using memcache to try to get performance on variable initialization is not what memcache is used for.

**However if you are calculating the values of that array, you may want to check out caching techniques.**

You should however, consider [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) in either case for optimizing the intermediate code.

Answer (score 1):

For benchmark you can use this [xhprof](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using an opcode cache, e.g. [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php), you get rid of a lot of the start-up time.